# How can i create a package compiled on raspberry pi?

Tags: c++, raspberrypi, ros-groovy, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I´ve created a package in ROS Groovy installed on Ubuntu 12.04 with two very simple nodes that communicate sending a float32 to start learning with ROS but what i really need is to implemnet this on raspberry pi.I did the same steps in the two cases and it works on the computer but I get an error during compilation on the raspberry pi package.In the case of the raspberry pi i used leafpad text editor to create the two cpp files.
Where may be the error?Are the cpp files created on Leafpad valid?

The error that i get is next>

Linking CXX executable ../bin/enviarnum
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/libboost_signals-mt.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/libboost_regex-mt.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/enviarnum.dir/build.make:103: recipe for target '../bin/enviarnum' failed
make[3]: *** [../bin/enviarnum] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/pruebas/build'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197043/how-can-i-create-a-package-compiled-on-raspberry-pi?/) by [MarcosM](https://answers.ros.org/users/20743/marcosm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-11-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-11-09**:
It would be helpful to share the error message you get while compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the error message shows, you don't have boost libraries installed. I am not sure for the raspberry Pi but from what I saw boost is available in the repository.

> sudo apt-get install libboost1.50-all

should fix your problem (not sure though which is the last version available for arm architectures).

If not, you could download boost and compile it by yourself but this would take a lot of time if done directly on the raspberry Pi (better do it on a raspberry emulator on your computer)

[Boost webpage](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_57_0.html)

The text editor doesn't have any influence on your cpp file. Cpp files are just text.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0